# What mean $\sup_t \Pr\{a(t)<b(t)\}<\varepsilon$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given two process $a(t)$ and $b(t)$,what mean in term of probability that :

$$\sup_t \Pr\{\tilde S(t)<\Psi(t)\}<\varepsilon.$$

THANKS.

---

$\qquad$ [image: Show it with a bang]

Comment: As stated, it seems to be nonsense.  Perhaps the author put a $\}$ in the wrong place or something.

Comment: hello, i have add the source as pecture

Comment: OK, I will correct your question to match the picture... now it makes sense!  The problem was that the OP incorrectly added some braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon$, which is probably to be thought of as a small number, this expression (call it $T$) is the largest value of $t$ (perhaps that's time) for which the probability that $\tilde S(t) < \Psi(t)$ is less than $\varepsilon$, i.e. small.

That is, whenever $t < T$ you know that the probability that $\tilde S(t) < \Psi(t)$ is small. For larger values of $t$ you don't have that guarantee.

(Strictly speaking, you might have an equality rather than an inequality at that value of $t$.)

Comment: so it mean that when $s(t)<\Psi(t)$ then the prorbability  $Pr(s(t)<\Psi(t))$ is colse to zero?

Comment: No. See my edit.